# Android sqlite возвращает false во всех эмуляторах кроме одного

Tags: android, sqlite, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Написал приложение под андроид, все данные выбираются из бд и отображаются на экране. Тестировал в genymotion на модели Google Galaxy Nexsus 4.2.2 API 17, все было отлично. Но на всех остальных моделях, когда попытался запустить, данные из базы данных возвращают **false**.
Например:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users", null);
```

здесь cursor вернет **false**, на любой запрос, любой столбец и тд. 
А вот в той модели, что указал выше, все отлично работает. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким ?

p.s. пробовал на эмуляторах с такой же версией 4.2.2 и API 17, все равно не работает.

Comment: Весь код работы с курсором покажите. Плюс, что значит "здесь cursor вернет false"? Вы про `cursor.moveToFirst()` или что? Ну и да, `cursor.close()` вызываете?

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил давно, но вдруг кому-то поможет.
Для приложения было важно, иметь уже заготовленную базу данных. Проблема оказалась в том, что база данных создается при установке приложения, а не хранится в собранном apk файле. И по этому при запуске приложения на любом новом устройстве, запросы к базе возвращали false, так как она была пустой.

Проблема решилось хранением дампа базы в проекте в папке assets, а при первом запуске проверялось наличие дампа, и производилось копирование базы данных во внутреннюю директорию проекта databases (где должна быть база). После дамп удаляем.